# Is there an .exe in Windows 10 that runs in background and does absolutely nothing? And if not, how can I make one?

Tags: windows-10, discord

I want to use this .exe to set a custom "Playing" status in Discord, so it would need to be compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more efficient ways, but the simplest is to install [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com) and then create a new text file in Notepad called `Playing.ahk` with the following line:

```
#persistent
```

Right-click on the file and select "Compile Script" to create an exe. Once you have the exe, you can uninstall AutoHotKey if you want.

When you run it, a "H" icon will appear in your system tray. You can right-click on this to bring up a menu, one of the options will be to close the exe.

On my 16GB core i5 laptop it uses 0% CPU and 1.3 MB. If you want something that uses less memory then you’re going to need to look at writing an equivalent in a language such as C.

Comment: that sounds like exactly what i want. Thanks a lot!